# Instantiating a class instance returns an error on __init__( )

Tags: python, python-class

I have defined the following classes in Python:

```
class DynamicalModel(abc.ABC):
    """Simulation of a dynamical model to be applied in the iLQR solution."""

    _id = 0

    def __init__(self, n_x, n_u, dt, id=None):
        if not id:
            id = DynamicalModel._id
            DynamicalModel._id += 1

        self.n_x = n_x
        self.n_u = n_u
        self.dt = dt
        self.id = id
        self.NX_EYE = np.eye(self.n_x, dtype=np.float32)

    def __call__(self, x, u):
        """Zero-order hold to integrate continuous dynamics f"""
        return x + self.f(x, u) * self.dt
        # Single RK4 integration of continuous dynamics.
        # k1 = self.dt * self.f(x, u)
        # k2 = self.dt * self.f(x + 0.5 * k1, u)
        # k3 = self.dt * self.f(x + 0.5 * k2, u)
        # k4 = self.dt * self.f(x + k3, u)
        # x += (k1 + 2.0 * k2 + 2.0 * k3 + k4) / 6.0
        # return x

    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f():
        """Continuous derivative of dynamics with respect to time"""
        pass

    def linearize(self, x: torch.tensor, u: torch.tensor, discrete=False):
        """Compute the Jacobian linearization of the dynamics for a particular state
        and controls for all players.
        """

        A, B = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(self.f, (x, u))

        if discrete:
            return A, B

        # Compute the discretized jacobians with euler integration.
        A = self.dt * A.reshape(self.n_x, self.n_x) + self.NX_EYE
        B = self.dt * B.reshape(self.n_x, self.n_u)
        return A, B

    @classmethod
    def _reset_ids(cls):
        cls._id = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}(n_x: {self.n_x}, n_u: {self.n_u}, id: {self.id})"


class AnalyticalModel(DynamicalModel):
    """Mix-in for analytical linearization"""

    def __init__(self, A_num, B_num):

        self.A_num = A_num
        self.B_num = B_num

    def f(self, x, u):
        return self._f(x, u)

    def linearize(self, x, u):
        
        return self.A_num(x, u), self.B_num(x, u)


class UnicycleDynamics4dSymbolic(AnalyticalModel):
    def __init__(self, dt, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(4, 2, dt, *args, **kwargs)

        p_x, p_y, v, theta, omega, a = sym.symbols('p_x p_y v theta omega a')
        x = sym.Matrix([p_x, p_y, v, theta])
        u = sym.Matrix([a, omega])

        x_dot = sym.Matrix([
            x[2]*sym.cos(x[3]),
            x[2]*sym.sin(x[3]),
            u[0],
            u[1],
        ])

        A = x_dot.jacobian(x)
        B = x_dot.jacobian(u)

        self._f = sym.lambdify((x, u), sym.Array(x_dot)[:,0])
        self.A_num = sym.lambdify((x, u), A)
        self.B_num = sym.lambdify((x, u), B)
```

when I tried to call the `UnicycleDynamics` class :

```
dec.UnicycleDynamics4dSymbolic(dt)
```

The following error popped up:

```
    175 class UnicycleDynamics4dSymbolic(AnalyticalModel):
    176     def __init__(self, dt, *args, **kwargs):
--> 177         super().__init__(4, 2, dt, *args, **kwargs)
    178 
    179         p_x, p_y, v, theta, omega, a = sym.symbols('p_x p_y v theta omega a')

TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I don't understand how exactly I have passed 4 arguments? I intend to create a child class from `AnalyticalModel`, but `AnalyticalModel` is a child class of `DynamicalModel`. I am a little confused about how to fix this error.

Comment: AnayliticalModel's `__init__()`: `def __init__(self, A_num, B_num):`

Comment: So, `UnicycleDynamics4dSymbolic` is based on `AnalyticalModel`, which has `def __init__(self, A_num, B_num):`, which only takes 3 arguments; when you call `super()`, you are calling `AnalyticalModel`'s `__init__`. Maybe you intended to have `AnalyticalModel` call its `super()` as well, so that it calls the constructor for `DynamicalModel`, which has the right number of args? The constructor's signature being: `def __init__(self, n_x, n_u, dt, id=None)`. You'd just have to change `AnalyticalModel`'s constructor to take in that number of args and pass them to the call to `super()`.

Comment: It seems like you think that `super()` refers to the highest-level superclass, the base one in the chain of inheritance. But it actually just refers to the direct parent of the class you're in; so, that's why `super()` is referring to `AnalyticalModel` and not `DynamicalModel`. Edit: You can pass in the type to `super()` directly, FYI: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super